# Prepared Statements Iterate Through Record Set

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I have two tables: `ContractCluster` (with `ContractClusterID` as a primary key), and `Contract` (with `ContractID` as a primary key, `ContractClusterID` as a foreign key). I am trying to iterate through the returned record set of `ContractClusterID` and to return all `ContractID` with the corresponding `ContractClusterID` foreign key from the table.  For some reason I can't get it working. I only receive the data for the very first row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$PoolID = $_POST['PoolID'];
$query = "SELECT ContractCluster.ContractClusterID,ContractCluster.PoolID FROM ContractCluster WHERE ContractCluster.PoolID=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $PoolID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($ContractClusterID, $PoolID);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++) {
    $stmt->fetch();

   echo "<p>Rows Returned (ClusterID):$numrows</p>";
echo "Contract Cluster ID:  $ContractClusterID, Pool ID: $PoolID</br></br>";

    $ContractClusterID = $ContractClusterID;
    $query = "SELECT Contract.ContractID FROM Contract WHERE Contract.ContractClusterID=? ";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $ContractClusterID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($ContractID);
    echo "<p>Rows Returned (ContractID): '.$numrows.'</p>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++) {
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo "Contract ID: $ContractID </br>";
        };
 };
```

Comment: what 'numrows' value shows to you this line: `echo "<p>Rows Returned (ContractID): '.$numrows.'</p>";` ?

Comment: It shows the correct number of rows with ContractID in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reusing variables like `$i`, this will mess up your loops.

Also it's a good idea to prepare queries outside a loop, and execute inside. This prevents a bunch of overhead and is one of the major advantages of prepared statements.

If you want to make your life easier, I'd strongly recommend using PDO and avoiding all that mess with `bind_param()` and `bind_result()`. It also allows you to dump the entire result set into an array at once, rather than messing with `fetch()` and `for` loops. This is untested, but should give you a start.

```
$PoolID = $_POST['PoolID'];

$query1 = "SELECT ContractCluster.ContractClusterID,ContractCluster.PoolID FROM ContractCluster WHERE ContractCluster.PoolID=?";
$query2 = "SELECT Contract.ContractID FROM Contract WHERE Contract.ContractClusterID=?";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);

$stmt1->execute(array($PoolID));
$rows1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$numrows1 = count($rows1);
foreach ($rows1 as $row1) {
    echo "<p>Rows Returned (ClusterID):$numrows1</p>";
    echo "Contract Cluster ID: $row1[ContractClusterID], Pool ID: $row1[PoolID]</br></br>";
    $stmt2->execute(array($row1["ContractClusterID"]));
    $rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $numrows2 = count($rows2);
    echo "<p>Rows Returned (ContractID): $numrows2</p>";
    foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
        echo "Contract ID: $row2[ContractID] </br>";
    }
 }
```

If you insist on using MySQLi, just change the variables `$i`, `$numrows`, and `$stmt` in the inner loop of your existing code and it should work. But your code will still be dreadfully inefficient; at least move the statement preparation out of the loop.

All that said, it's also worth asking if this couldn't be done with a join:

```
SELECT cc.ContractClusterID, cc.PoolID, c.ContractID
FROM ContractCluster cc
LEFT JOIN Contract c
    USING (ContractClusterID)
WHERE cc.PoolID = ?
```

Comment: this code didn't work for me. Am I missing anything? It seems that it stops after this line:
    $stmt1->execute(array($PoolID));

Comment: Like I said, this code is for PDO, so make sure that `$db` is a PDO object and not a mysqli one.

Comment: I need to stick with mysqli. I still can't figure it out.I tried 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) but still no results.

Comment: If you want to do that,change the variable names for `$i`, and `$numrows` in the inner loop.